# How can I fix the If and structure problem in C?

Tags: c, date, if-statement

My program should ask user for last full moon date, check if data is correct and then ask user does he want to see dates of next or previouse full moons and how many. I have some problems with "if"and "else if". I don't know why but program basiclly acts like it doesn't see that user gave anything in this line `scanf_s("%s", &czy_kolejne);` and goes straight to `else{printf("\nBłędny znak."); }`. I'm also not sure if structure for date is the best way to do it, becasue it have some problem with previouse dates. Could someone give me any advice ?

```
#include<time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int rok, miesiac, dzien;
    char czy_kolejne;
    int kolejne_pelnie;
    int poprzednie_pelnie;
    printf_s("Kiedy byla ostatnia pelnia ? (DD.MM.YYYY): ");
    scanf_s("%d.%d.%d", &dzien, &miesiac, &rok);

    if (rok >= 0)
    {
        if (miesiac >= 1 && miesiac <= 12)
        {
            if ((dzien >= 1 && dzien <= 31) && (miesiac == 1 || miesiac == 3 || miesiac == 5 || miesiac == 7 || miesiac == 8))
            {
                printf_s("Poprawna data. %d.%02d.%d", dzien, miesiac, rok);
            }
            else if ((dzien >= 1 && dzien <= 31) && (miesiac == 10 || miesiac == 12))
            {
                printf_s("Poprawna data. %d.%d.%d", dzien, miesiac, rok);
            }
            else if ((dzien >= 1 && dzien <= 30) && (miesiac == 4 || miesiac == 6 || miesiac == 9))
            {
                printf_s("Poprawna data. %d.%02d.%d", dzien, miesiac, rok);
            }
            else if ((dzien >= 1 && dzien <= 30) && miesiac == 11)
            {
                printf_s("Poprawna data. %d.%d.%d", dzien, miesiac, rok);
            }
            else if ((dzien >= 1 && dzien <= 28) && miesiac == 2)
            {
                printf_s("Poprawna data. %d.%02d.%d", dzien, miesiac, rok);
            }
            else if (dzien == 29 && miesiac == 2 && (rok % 400 == 0 || (rok % 4 == 0 && rok % 100 != 0)))
            {
                printf_s("Poprawna data. %d.%02d.%d", dzien, miesiac, rok);
            }
            else
            {
                printf_s("Liczba dni w miesiacu jest bledna.");
            }
        }

        else
        {
            printf_s("Nie ma tylu miesiecy.");
        }
    }

    struct tm  t = { 0 };
    t.tm_mday = dzien;
    t.tm_mon = miesiac - 1;
    t.tm_year = rok - 1900;
    int skip = 29;
    t.tm_mday += skip;
    mktime(&t);
    char buffer[30];

    printf("\nCzy wyliczyc daty kolejnych pelni ? (T/N)");
    scanf_s("%s", &czy_kolejne); //The problem starts right here.//

    if ((czy_kolejne=='t') || (czy_kolejne=='T'))
    {

        printf_s("\nIle dat w przod?");
        scanf_s("%d", &kolejne_pelnie);
        for (int i = 1; i <= kolejne_pelnie; i++)
        {
            int skip = 29 * i;
            t.tm_mday += skip;
            strftime(buffer, 30, "\n%d-%m-%Y", &t);
            puts(buffer);
        }
    }
    else if ((czy_kolejne=='n') || (czy_kolejne=='N'))
    {

        printf_s("\nIle dat w tył wyliczyc?");
        scanf_s("%d", &poprzednie_pelnie);
        for (int i= 1; i <= poprzednie_pelnie; i++)
        {
            int skip = 29 * i;
            t.tm_mday -= skip;
            strftime(buffer, 30, "\n%d.%m.%Y", &t);
            puts(buffer);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nBłędny znak.");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf_s("%s", &czy_kolejne)` reads a *string* (a NUL-terminated sequence of `char`s), but you're writing it into a variable declared to be a single `char`.  You're thus corrupting memory and entering the realm of undefined behavior.  Also, whether you use the "safe" version of `scanf` or not, `scanf` is very hard to use correctly.  It's usually much simpler to read an entire line of input with `fgets`, to remove the trailing newline if necessary, and to do any further parsing with `sscanf`.

Answer (score 1):

At least two things are wrong with `scanf_s("%s", &czy_kolejne)`, when `czy_kolejne` is of datatype `char`:

First, `%s` will read in a `0`-terminated string, but you provide a buffer of type `char`; this is undefined behaviour, very likely just corrupting memory and leading to weird results. For reading in exactly one character use format `"%c"`.

Second, if you make `czy_kolejne` to a char array, e.g. `char czy_kolejne[10]`, then `scanf_s` with a format `%s`is OK, but it requires an additional argument indicating the buffer size. I.e. you'd have to write `scanf_s("%s", &czy_kolejne, sizeof(czy_kolejne))`.

Comment: Ok I tryed both ```scanf_s("%c", &czy_kolejne)``` and  ```scanf_s("%c", &czy_kolejne, sizeof(czy_kolejne))```. In both situations program doesn't read char from user and skips to the "else" and ends.